# Python for web development in Apache

Tags: python, apache, mod-python

I've been playing with mod_python in apache2 which seems to work differently than python does in general - there's a bit different syntax and things you need to do. It's not very well documented and after a few days of playing with it, I'm really not seeing the point of mod_python at all, especially when things like php are so well documented and available.

I can see how Python works well for system programming, but can anyone give any information as to why I shouldn't just dump python for a web-based application?

Comment: "there's a bit different syntax"  Please provide the specific example for this.

Answer (score 29):

1. Don't use mod_python. A common mistake is take mod_python as "mod_php, but for python" and that is **not true**. Use [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) instead.
2. Choose a web framework. [CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org/). [Pylons](http://pylonshq.com). [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/).
3. Look at [wsgi.org](http://wsgi.org)

Comment: "Use mod_wsgi instead" Seconded!  Or SCGI if you find it easier not to be running in the same process.

Comment: You can run mod_wsgi in a separate process as well.  Try reading about "mod_wsgi daemon mode."

Comment: mod_wsgi's daemon mode is *not* available under Windows, though.

Answer (score 6):

mod_python wasn't really made for doing basic webprogramming.  I suggest you go with a framework:

- [django](http://www.djangoproject.com/)
- [cherrypy](http://cherrypy.org)
- [web.py](http://webpy.org)

My suggestion is to give python some time.  It's easy to get simplicity and lack of power confused.  :)